# Power Query - Please rebuild this data combination

Tags: powerquery

i have this error on the power query.

> Formula.Firewall: Query 'Gunduz' (step 'Source') references other
>   queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please
>   rebuild this data combination.

i have the query which is working fine on SQL side but Power Query has a problem with it. First Table7 is a "connection only" as a separate query.

Output text of the query is also fine

[image: Screenshot of the query text]

The Query is as follows :

```
let

    param1 = Table7,

    ilktarih = Text.From(param1 {0} [Value]),

    sontarih = Text.From(param1 {1} [Value]),

    dbQuery = " SELECT #(lf)#(tab)   pg.pgrpName1#(tab)#(tab)#(tab) [Santiye],#(lf)#(tab)   p.prsncode            [Sicil No],#(lf)       p.[prsnname1]         [Adi],#(lf)       p.[prsnname2]         [Soyadi],#(lf)       CLT.clntName1#(tab)#(tab) [Firmasi],#(lf)       fg3.grp3Name1#(tab)#(tab) [Gorevi],#(lf)       prf.pcntrName1#(tab)#(tab) [Ekibi],#(lf)       lnk11.lgrp11Name1#(tab) [Kaldigi Yer],#(lf)       lnk12.lgrp12Name1 +' - '+lnk12.lgrp12Name2 [Kamp/Adres],#(lf)       lnk13.lgrp13Name1#(tab) [Oda No],#(lf)       cast(t.ioTransactionDate as date) as Tarih,#(lf)       t.[iotransactiondate] [Giris Tarihi/Saati],#(lf)       (SELECT #(lf)#(tab)   #(lf)        t2.[iotransactiondate] #(lf)       #(lf)       #(lf)#(tab)#(tab)FROM   [Exen].[dbo].[IOTransaction] t2#(lf)       #(lf)#(tab)   #(lf)#(tab)#(tab)#(tab)  #(tab)  #(tab)  #(tab)#(lf)#(tab)#(tab)WHERE  ( t2.[iotransactiondate] = (SELECT Min(m.[ioTransactionDate])#(lf)                                  FROM   IOTransaction m#(lf)                                  WHERE  m.ioPrsnRefId = t2.ioPrsnRefId#(lf)                                         AND Cast(m.[iotransactiondate] AS DATE)#(lf)                                             = Cast#(lf)                                             (#(lf)                                             t2.[iotransactiondate] AS DATE)#(lf)                                  GROUP  BY m.ioPrsnRefId)#(lf)          OR t2.[iotransactiondate] = (SELECT Max(m.[iotransactiondate])#(lf)                                      FROM   IOTransaction m#(lf)                                      WHERE  m.ioPrsnRefId = t2.ioPrsnRefId#(lf)                                             AND Cast(m.[iotransactiondate] AS#(lf)                                                      DATE) =#(lf)                                                 Cast(#(lf)                                                 t2.[iotransactiondate] AS DATE)#(lf)                                      GROUP  BY m.ioPrsnRefId) )#(lf)       #(lf)       #(lf)       and ioStatus = 1#(lf)       and cast(t2.ioTransactionDate as date) = cast(t.ioTransactionDate as date) and t.ioPrsnRefId = t2.ioPrsnRefId#(lf)GROUP  BY #(lf)          t2.[iotransactiondate]#(lf)          #(lf)         )#(lf)       #(lf)       #(lf)       #(lf)       AS  [Cikis Tarihi/Saati],#(lf)       prsnEText4 [Vardiya],#(lf)       tz.tzoneName1 [GECE/GUNDUZ]#(lf)       #(lf)       #(lf)FROM   [Exen].[dbo].[IOTransaction] t#(lf)       LEFT JOIN dbo.person p#(lf)              ON t.ioPrsnRefId = p.prsnRefId#(lf)       LEFT JOIN dbo.PersonShift ps#(lf)#(tab)#(tab)#(tab)  ON ps.psPrsnRefId = p.prsnRefId#(lf)#(tab)   LEFT JOIN dbo.TimeZoneMess tz#(lf)#(tab)#(tab)#(tab)  ON tz.tzoneRefId = ps.psTzoneRefId#(lf)#(tab)   LEFT JOIN dbo.[PersonGroup] pg#(lf)#(tab)#(tab)#(tab)  ON pg.pgrpRefId = p.prsnPgrpRefId#(tab)#(lf)#(tab)   LEFT JOIN FreeGroup3 fg3#(lf)#(tab)#(tab)#(tab)  ON fg3.grp3RefId = p.prsnGrp3RefId#(lf)#(tab)   left join Client CLT#(lf)#(tab)#(tab)#(tab)  ON CLT.clntRefId = P.prsnClntRefId#(lf)#(tab)   LEFT JOIN [ProfitCenter] prf#(lf)#(tab)#(tab)#(tab)  ON prf.pcntrRefId = p.prsnPcntrRefId#(tab)#(lf)#(tab)   LEFT JOIN LinkedGroup11 lnk11#(lf)#(tab)#(tab)#(tab)  ON lnk11.lgrp11RefId = p.prsnLgrp11RefId#(tab)#(lf)#(tab)   LEFT JOIN LinkedGroup12 lnk12#(lf)#(tab)#(tab)#(tab)  ON lnk12.lgrp12RefId = p.prsnLgrp12RefId#(tab)#(lf)#(tab)   LEFT JOIN LinkedGroup13 lnk13#(lf)#(tab)#(tab)#(tab)  ON lnk13.lgrp13RefId = p.prsnLgrp13RefId#(lf)#(tab)   #(lf)#(tab)#(tab)#(tab)  #(tab)  #(tab)  #(tab)#(lf)WHERE  ( t.[iotransactiondate] = (SELECT Min(m.[ioTransactionDate])#(lf)                                  FROM   IOTransaction m#(lf)                                  WHERE  m.ioPrsnRefId = t.ioPrsnRefId#(lf)                                         AND Cast(m.[iotransactiondate] AS DATE)#(lf)                                             = Cast#(lf)                                             (#(lf)                                             t.[iotransactiondate] AS DATE)#(lf)                                  GROUP  BY m.ioPrsnRefId)#(lf)          OR t.[iotransactiondate] = (SELECT Max(m.[iotransactiondate])#(lf)                                      FROM   IOTransaction m#(lf)                                      WHERE  m.ioPrsnRefId = t.ioPrsnRefId#(lf)                                             AND Cast(m.[iotransactiondate] AS#(lf)                                                      DATE) =#(lf)                                                 Cast(#(lf)                                                 t.[iotransactiondate] AS DATE)#(lf)                                      GROUP  BY m.ioPrsnRefId) )#(lf)       AND p.[prsnname1] IS NOT NULL#(lf)       AND t.iotransactiondate >= '" & ilktarih & "'#(lf)       AND t.iotransactiondate <= '" & sontarih & "'#(lf)       AND ps.psStartDate <= t.[iotransactiondate]#(lf)       AND ps.psFinishDate > t.[iotransactiondate] #(lf)       AND tz.tzoneRefId =4#(lf)       and ioStatus = 0#(lf)GROUP  BY pg.pgrpName1#(tab),#(lf)#(tab)#(tab)  t.ioPrsnRefId,#(lf)          prsncode,#(lf)          prsnname1,#(lf)          prsnname2,#(lf)          t.[iotransactiondate],#(lf)          t.iostatus,#(lf)          tz.tzoneName1,#(lf)          ps.psStartDate,#(lf)          ps.psFinishDate,#(lf)          prsnEText4,#(lf)          fg3.grp3Name1,#(lf)          CLT.clntName1,#(lf)          prf.pcntrName1,#(lf)          lgrp11Name1,#(lf)          lgrp12Name1,#(lf)          lgrp12Name2,#(lf)          lgrp13Name1",

    Source = Sql.Database("Mayak", "Exen", [Query=dbQuery])
in
    Source
```

On the other hand, another server, another database similar code is working just fine...

```
let
     param = TarihAraligi,

    ilktarih = param {0} [Custom],
    sontarih = param {1} [Custom],

    dbQuery  = "SELECT #(lf)H.ACCOUNTCODE collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1254_CI_AS AS 'HESAP NO', #(lf)E.DEFINITION_ collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1254_CI_AS AS 'HESAP ADI', #(lf)E.EXTNAME collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1254_CI_AS AS 'HESAP ADI-2', #(lf)E.SPECODE collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1254_CI_AS AS 'HESAP OZELKODU', #(lf)SUM(H.DEBIT) 'BORC',  #(lf)SUM(H.CREDIT) #(lf)'ALACAK', SUM(H.DEBIT-H.CREDIT) 'BAKIYE', #(lf)SUM((1-H.SIGN)*H.REPORTNET) 'DOVIZ BORC',#(lf)SUM(H.SIGN*H.REPORTNET) 'DOVIZ ALACAK', #(lf)SUM((1-H.SIGN)*H.REPORTNET-H.SIGN*H.REPORTNET) 'DOVIZ BAKIYE', #(lf)SUM(H.EMUDEBIT) 'EURO BORC', SUM(H.EMUCREDIT) 'EURO ALACAK', #(lf)SUM(H.EMUDEBIT-H.EMUCREDIT) 'EURO BAKIYE', #(lf)E.UNITS collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1254_CI_AS AS 'BIRIM' #(lf)FROM LG_076_01_EMFLINE H #(lf)LEFT JOIN LG_076_EMUHACC E ON E.LOGICALREF=H.ACCOUNTREF #(lf)WHERE (H.TRCODE IN (1,2,3,4,6,7)) AND (H.CANCELLED = 0) AND (H.STATUS = 0) AND H.DATE_>='" & ilktarih & "' AND  H.DATE_<='" & sontarih & "' #(lf)GROUP BY H.ACCOUNTCODE, E.DEFINITION_, E.EXTNAME, E.SPECODE, E.UNITS #(lf)",

    Source = Sql.Database("teqsql", "logo", [Query=dbQuery])
in
    Source
```

Comment: solved. i had two different connections to the database, one via IP and another with the server name... removing one of them solved the problem !

also set the `Always ignore privacy` in the settings...

Comment: These are two different ways to solve the problem of data privacy. The first tells Powerquery that the two sources are the same, so there's no question of data privacy. The other turns off the feature completely, which is more risky.

Comment: @CarlWalsh I think setting the `ignore privacy` solved my problem. but developers shall solve this problem so we dont have to put ourselves into risk.