# Create single Azure Analysis Services table from many blobs in Data Lake Store

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-analysis-services

I'm new to analysis services and data lake, working on a POC.  I've used data factory to pull in some TSV data from blob storage, which is logically organized as small "partition" blobs (thousands of blobs). I have a root folder that can be thought of as containing the whole table, containing subfolders that logically represent partitioning by, say, customer - these contain subfolders that loggically represent partitioning the customer's data by, say, date.  I want to model this whole folder/blob structure as one table in Analysis Services, but can't seem to figure out how.  I have seen the blog posts and examples that create a single AAS table from a single ADLS file, but information on other data file layouts seems sparse.  Is my approach to this wrong, or am I just missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2017/05/30/building-an-azure-analysis-services-model-on-top-of-azure-blob-storage-part-2/?) provides instructions on appending multiple blobs into a single table.

Then the [part 3 blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2017/06/22/building-an-azure-analysis-services-model-on-top-of-azure-blob-storage-part-3/?) describes creating some Analysis Services partitions to improve processing performance.

Finally this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2017/09/05/using-azure-analysis-services-on-top-of-azure-data-lake-storage/?) describes connecting to Azure Data Lake Store (as opposed to Azure Blob Storage in the prior posts).

I would use those approaches to create say 20-200 partitions (not thousands) in Azure Analysis Services. Partitions should generally be at least 8 million rows to get optimal compression and performance. I assume that will require appending several blobs together in order to achieve that size.

Comment: I am reviewing those blog posts again, and I think what I'm missing is how to "combine files" when they are not all together in one folder.  The structure I am importing from is laid out like <table>/customer/week/date/*.csv (thousands of csv's per date folder), and I want all customers in one table (would probably then be partitioned by week).  The M syntax is still a bit elusive to me, and my attempts to search for syntax just lead to screenshots of excel that don't really give me an idea of how the M language works.  I'm still digging, but could use a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: @Brandon I would suggest using the UI to append tables to learn the syntax. The syntax you're looking for would be `#"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({Step1, Step2})` as that would let you append two tables or steps together

Comment: I'll check that out...after posting my last reply, I came upon this that I think will help me along: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46982551/nest-load-a-folder-path-power-query/47044665#47044665